# If there are double entries in a dataframe how do I delete both the entries?

Tags: r

The idea is not removing one of the duplicate rows but all repeated rows.

Data that I Have now

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| AB | 75 |
| AB | 75 |
| BC | 50 |
| CD | 70 |

Expected Result

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| BC | 50 |
| CD | 70 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use group_by to detect the combinations of variables with duplicates and filter based on group size.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.2
withdups <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("AB", "AB", "BC", "CD"),
             Score = c(75L, 75L, 50L, 70L)
)

withdups %>% 
  group_by(Name, Score) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   Name, Score [2]
#>   Name  Score
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 BC       50
#> 2 CD       70
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: or `group_by_all()` if you have multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
withdups %>%
add_count(Name, Score) %>%
filter(n == 1)
```